# output parameter in stored procedure not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am new with stored procedures.

I have simple stored procedure for addition of two numbers as follows:

```
alter proc simpleProc 
(
    @Tax int ,
    @TotalAmount int,
    @sum int output     
)
as
BEGIN
set @sum=(@Tax+@TotalAmount)
print @sum
END
```

As we can see in this `@sum` is output parameter.

But when I execute it as follows:

```
exec simpleProc 908,82
```

It gives me the following error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure simpleProc, Line 0
>   Procedure or Function 'simpleProc' expects parameter '@sum', which was not supplied.

I have mentioned `@sum` as output parameter, but then also its demanding me to input `@sum` parameter.

What can be the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the procedure a variable where the output can be stored

```
declare @sum int
exec simpleProc 908, 82, @sum output
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it you haven't provided output parameter.
Try this

```
    Declare @op int
    exec simpleProc 908,82,@op output
    //use op variable
```